# MVC . Search by more than one criteria

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a view where I can search through the record.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Project", FormMethod.Get, new { role = "form" }))
{

    <div class="input-group">
        <input name="Query" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
        <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0;">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
        </span>
    </div>
}

@if (Model.Any())
{
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Year
                </th>
                <th>
                    Project
                </th>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>
                <th>

                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.PROJ_YEAR)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.PROJ_NAME)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.PROJ_STATUS)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>}
else
{
    <p style="margin:20px 0;">No Projects found.</p>
}
```

and here is the controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int page = 1, string Query = null)

{
    var projectList = db.TBL_PROJECTS.Include(x => x.TBL_STATUS).Where(x => x.PROJ_CAT == 1).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Query))
        {
            projectList = projectList
                .Where(x => x.PROJ_NAME.ToLower().Contains(Query.ToLower()))
                .ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);

            if (projectList.Count() == 0)
            {
               var list = db.TBL_PROJECTS.Include(x => x.TBL_STATUS).Where(x => x.PROJ_CAT == 1).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);
               projectList = list
               .Where(x => x.PROJ_YEAR.ToLower().Contains(Query.ToLower()))
              .ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);

            }

        }
    return View(new PagedList.PagedList<TBL_PROJECT>(projectList, page, 15));
}
```

When I perform search, it will only perform search based on PROJ_NAME. 
I want to search by the "PROJ_YEAR" too. When I search "1998", no record will be found. When I search "Paint Job" which falls in the year 1998, record will be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. This might come useful for someone having this kind of issue later. This is how I did it.

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Query))
        {
            projectList = projectList
                .Where(x => x.PROJ_NAME.ToLower().Contains(Query.ToLower()))
                .ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);
            if (projectList.Count() == 0)
            {
                var list = db.TBL_PROJECTS.Include(x => x.TBL_STATUS).Where(x => x.PROJ_CAT == 1).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);
                var k = list
                .Where(x => x.PROJ_YEAR != null)
                .ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);
                projectList = k
                .Where(x => x.PROJ_YEAR.ToLower().Contains(Query.ToLower()))
                .ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 projectList = projectList
                .Where(x => x.PROJ_NAME.ToLower().Contains(Query.ToLower())
                         || x.PROJ_YEAR = Int32.Parse(Query)  )
                .ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);
```

Or use `Int32.TryParse()`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are comparing only Project Name column. Therefor when you submit the year it does not work. You should modify your controller, for example:

```
public ActionResult Index(int page = 1, string Query = null)

    {
        var projectList = db.TBL_PROJECTS.Include(x => x.TBL_STATUS).Where(x => x.PROJ_CAT == 1).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Query))
        {
            projectList = projectList
                .Where(x => x.PROJ_NAME.ToLower().Contains(Query.ToLower())
                        || x.PROJ_YEAR.ToLower().Contains(Query.ToLower()))
                .ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);

        }

        return View(new PagedList.PagedList<TBL_PROJECT>(projectList, page, 15));
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and get this error instead. {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: In your code there are some issues can throw null exception. Try the ideas here, it mean you need to compare the year with the project name. For example when Query = null, it will throw exception at Query.ToLower(), or when your result is null it will throw exception at ToList()...

Comment: I've updated the controller code, but still the same error. Can you show some example code?

Comment: You should use debugger to check whether it null